# How can I pass a value from a field in a modal to a processing script using SEBLOD?

Tags: joomla-3.x, search, modal, seblod

I have a button in a list & search form that when clicked displays a modal where the user can select an item from a dropdown and click another button to call a processing script. The user can select multiple check boxes in the list view to apply the selected value to, which gets passed to the processing script via `$config['id']`.

I can't figure out how to capture the value selected in the dropdown however. I only appear to have access to `$config`, and nothing else.

Are there any other variables accessible to the processing script? Or can I pass one through somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to achieve this using the following in my processing script:

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$formVal = intval($app->input->get('dropdown', ''));
```

Where `dropdown` is the name of the dropdown box in the modal form. The value of the dropdown is an integer, hence using the `intval` function.